# security find-generic-password command for safari returning some garbage value

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension, nstask

I want to find the Safari Extensions List password from the keychain. I am doing it through NSTask now, As soon as we launch the task, it is printing some password. But When I store the password in some NSString using,
NSString * password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRead encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
it is returning some other value. Is there any other way to read the output of NSTask/NSPipe?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `NSData* dataRead` from "Safari Extensions List", just save it to a file:

```
[dataRead writeToFile:@"/tmp/extensions_list.plist" atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

There are two ways to find the safari password from the keychain.
1. Using API

```
   status = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
                                        NULL,            // default keychain
                                        service_length,  // length of service name
                                        cService_name,    // service name
                                        username_length,// length of account name
                                        cUser_name,    // account name
                                        &passwordLength,  // length of password
                                        &passwordData,        // pointer to password data
                                        NULL             // the item reference
                                        );
```

Here Service name is Extended Preferneces and username is Safari.

2. Using NSTask or Terminal :
      [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"find-generic-password",@"-g",@"-l", @"Safari Extensions List", nil]];

Terminal Command is 
security find-generic-password -l "Safari Extensions List" -g

Copy the Hexadecimal password from the ouput of the above command, delete 0x prefix from the password, convert it to NSData and then use NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData method, we can see the Safari Extensions List along with its enabled state.